# How can I autoplay an html video on Chrome 72, avoiding it to start or not start randomly?

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I have a short video that should autoplay in Chrome. I've read plenty about this problem and tried a lot of solutions. Presently my code to play the video is

```
<video autoplay="true" playsinline muted > 
    <source src="assets/video/somevideo.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

This plays the video, but in an apparently random way. Sometimes the video starts, sometimes not, showing a white screen instead.

The video format is compatible with Chrome ('sometimes' it starts correctly!). The html attributes should be correct, taking into account the limitation of chrome in playing not muted videos.

What could be the problem and how can I play the video, being sure it will always be played?

Comment: To be sure it will always be played, add a splash screen that will force your users to interact with your page and mark it as trusted, in the click event call your video's play(). From there you have all controls over this element in any browser/os, even if it makes noisy sounds.

Comment: The video is a sort of intro/credit to an online application, I don't want the user to be forced to interact in that phase